# C++ MySQL c api user input into rows

Tags: c++, mysql

Trying to get user input to store data in Mysql database. 
after connecting to db, I have this for code

```
....
string itemName;
double itemPrice;
int itemInv;
cout << "Add New Item: " << endl << "Item Name: " << endl;
cin >> itemName;
cin.ignore(256, '\n');
cout << "Item Price: " << endl;
cin >> itemPrice;
cin.ignore(256, '\n');
cout << "Item Count: " << endl;
cin >> itemInv;
cin.ignore(256, '\n');

if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO kitchen (itemID, itemName, itemPrice, itemInv) VALUES(itemID, itemName, itemPrice, itemInv)")) {
   finish_with_errors(con);
 }

 mysql_close(con);
 exit(0);
```

It's throwing a syntax error after entering information.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'itemInv) VALUES(`itemID`,` itemName`, `itemPrice`, `itemInv`)' at line 1
```

I guess the question here is how to take user input and pass it as VALUES into the database?

Comment: The error message is quite clear, I would say, "You have an error in your SQL syntax". Next step: learn SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but answering a question that wasn't asked wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to those who commented. Since none of the suggestions really touched on what I was looking for. I decided to post the answer now that I have solved the issue.... 
So, my query syntax wasn't the issue and wasn't really the question. My question was more about C++ and how to take user input and make a query out of it. This is what I ended up doing...

```
string itemName;
string itemPrice;
string itemInv;

cout << "Add New Item: " << endl << "Item Name: " << endl;
cin >> itemName;
cin.ignore(256, '\n');
cout << "Item Price: " << endl;
cin >> itemPrice;
cin.ignore(256, '\n');
cout << "Item Count: " << endl;
cin >> itemInv;
cin.ignore(256, '\n');
//Add user input to query
string sqlString =  "INSERT INTO kitchen (itemID, itemName, itemPrice, itemInv) VALUES(itemId," + itemName + "," + itemPrice + "," + itemInv + ")";

const char *newString = sqlString.c_str();

//Add data to database
if (mysql_query( con, newString )) {
  finish_with_errors(con);
}

mysql_close(con);
exit(0);
}
```